# Dual boot with Windows 7 (3 partitions) on an Acer Aspire One

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, acer, aspire-one

I have an Acer Aspire One from the AO725 series, with a 320gb hard drive, preinstalled with Windows 7 home Premium. It has the following three partitions:

```
sda1 (ntfs) 13958 MB - the Acer recover partition
sda2 (ntfs) 35 MB - the boot sector?
sda3 (ntfs) 306006 MB - the main partition for everything else
```

What I thought of doing was making the 4th partition an extended partition, and then putting in three logical partitions -

```
one for root: /
one for home: /home, 
and one for swap.
```

(this way I get to keep the recover partition in case something happens to Windows) Are there any problems with that? (for example, will I be able to use the recovery partition if I ever need it?) Will a standard Ubuntu installer with manual partitioning handle all this well, or do I need to do something special to prevent Grub for overwriting the MBR badly?

Comment: I have to confess that I ended up letting Ubuntu's automatic installer handle the partitioning, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan of action looks OK to me.

I have never used the Windows recovery partition, so I can't say how it will work, in particular if it will delete the logical partitions and all it's contents.

Grub should be installed on sda (not sda1 or any of the other partitions) by default. This will overwrite the MBR and that is normal as grub will takeover the function of MBR and give you the choice to boot Ubuntu, Windows 7 normal use, or Windows 7 Recovery.